# xcode 4.3.2: guide document to deploy iphone to real device

Tags: iphone

I am trying to deploy an iphone application with Ad Hoc Distribution or Apple Store. I tried to search on internet to find guide document, but I only get iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standart_program_v2.6__final_3410.pdf
for iOS 3.1. So old with me because
My Xcode version is 4.3.2.
Does anyone know the guide document for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Guide to deploy iPhone/iPad apps to real device](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_iOS_5_Apps_on_the_iPhone_%E2%80%93_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles)